# My file has many double subscript but I do not know why

Tags: math-mode, errors, subscripts

[image]

I don't know why my Overleaf file has many errors about double subscript and it makes my photo can not load in PDF. Please help me.

Comment: `K_i_2` has two subscripts.

Comment: Unrelated, but it should be `\sigma'` and not `\sigma^{'}`

Comment: Elaborating a bit on the above comment: You have mostly two options here, depending on what you want: `K_{i2}` if you subscript is supposed to be i2 or `K_{i_2}` if you want 2 to be subscript to i which is in turn subscript to K. You are in fact already doing this in your code with lambda.

Comment: you have double subscripts on each of the marked lines, `\mu_i_2`, `k_i_2`,  this needs to be `{k_i}_2` or `k_{i2}` or `k_{i_2}` depending on the intended meaning and layout that you want

Answer (score 0):

You have double subscripts on each of the marked lines, `\mu_i_2`, `k_i_2`, this needs to be `{k_i}_2` or `k_{i2}` or `k_{i_2}` depending on the intended meaning and layout that you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ {k_i}_2 + k_{i2} + k_{i_2} \]
\end{document}
```